# Terraform create same number of R53 records from different ACM certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I need to create 2 R53 records from 2 different ACM certificates. I'm using for_each to iterate on user inputs which would create the certificates.

```
locals {
    custom_domain_api = [
        {
            acm_name_api = join("",["api-",var.app_region,"-",var.application,"-",var.environment,lookup(var.r53_domain,var.environment)])
            customdomain_api = join("",["api-",var.app_region,"-",var.application,"-",var.environment,lookup(var.r53_domain,var.environment)])
        },
        {
            acm_name_api = join("",["ui-",var.app_region,"-",var.application,"-",var.environment,lookup(var.r53_domain,var.environment)])
            customdomain_api = join("",["ui-",var.app_region,"-",var.application,"-",var.environment,lookup(var.r53_domain,var.environment)])
        }
    ]
}


resource "aws_acm_certificate" "acm_api" {
    provider = aws.main
    for_each = {
        for index, api in local.custom_domain_api:
        api.customdomain_api => api
    }
    domain_name = each.value.acm_name_api
    validation_method = "DNS"
    tags = merge(
        {NAME = each.value.acm_name_api},
        local.common_tags
    )
}
```

The above code work fine, but when I get to the R53 creation part, none of the solutions I've read and tried
worked for me. I've used both for_each and for_each/for loop but I just get an error.

```
#1
resource "aws_route53_record" "acm_r53" {
    for_each = {
        for dvo in flatten(aws_acm_certificate.acm_api[*].domain_validation_options.domain_name) :
        dvo.domain_name => {
            name   = dvo.resource_record_name
            record = dvo.resource_record_value
        }
    }
    zone_id = local.r53_zoneid
    name = each.value.name
    type = "CNAME"
    ttl = "300"
    records = [each.value.record]
}


------

#2
resource "aws_route53_record" "acm_r53" {
    for_each = aws_acm_certificate.acm_api[each.key].domain_validation_options
    zone_id = local.r53_zoneid
    name = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.acm_api[each.key].domain_validation_options).resource_record_name
    type = "CNAME"
    ttl = "300"
    records = [tolist(aws_acm_certificate.acm_api[each.key].domain_validation_options).resource_record_value]
}


-----

#3
resource "aws_route53_record" "acm_r53" {
    for_each = aws_acm_certificate.acm_api[each.key].domain_validation_options
    zone_id = local.r53_zoneid
    name = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.acm_api[each.key].domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_name
    type = "CNAME"
    ttl = "300"
    records = [tolist(aws_acm_certificate.acm_api[each.key].domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_value]
}
```

Any solution on this using looping? As much as possible, I don't want to use individual resource blocks to create the certificates and record as that would unnecessarily lengthen the code.

For_each, For_each/For loop

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any restrictions on using external modules?

For me, the module https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-acm/ works perfectly, and there are only a few lines of code to have ACM created.